# use ClaRaLib with OMEdit

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I came across the feature rich modelica library ClaRa. It seems to need Dymola to run properly.  Is there a way to make it run with OMEdit or any other free editor? I keep getting errors "with no error message".

Comment: https://github.com/ClaRaLibrary

Comment: Note: not listed here yet: https://modelica.org/libraries

Answer (score 7):

The European governments frequently funds projects that involve software that only run on Microsoft Windows, a proprietary operating system originating in the USA. What's the point in that?

A lot of the research grants are intended to support/subsidise the industry to make them competitive with foreign industry. There are a lot of confidential prototypes in these kinds of projects so everything that is open is sort of a win.

Of course, it would be nice if ClaRa ran on OpenModelica. I didn't look into it much because it depends on TILMedia which does not specify a license (so we can't really use distribute it anyway).

Comment: ClaRa is more like a demo version, there is a paid version called ClaRa+, https://www.claralib.com/